# recursive multi variable lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda

I have seen an elegant solution for **recursive** functions using **lambda** in Python. As a matter of fact, I am very interested at applying this concept in **multi-variable** function, two variables — x and y — for instance. How can it be done in python?

The function itself is not important, but if it helps, here it comes the description: I have dictionaries containing one-layer dictionaries inside, as:

```
dicts = [{'A': {'a': 1}, 'B': {'a': 10}}, {'A': {'b':3}}, {'B': {'c': 31}}, {'A': {'j': 4, 't': 9}}, {'B': {'y': 400, 'r': 160}}]
```

And the keys in the inner dictionary does not repeat for the same given outer dictionary key. I want then to be merged, in a way that they result in:

```
result = {'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'j': 4, 't': 9}, 'B': {'a': 10, 'c': 31, 'r': 160, 'y': 400}}
```

The challenge of using **lambda function** to solve this kept my attention and focus. So if someone could give hints or help me solving this, I do appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `lambda` functions can only consist of a single expression. So when you want to do something complex with a lambda, what you are looking for is a one-liner.

```
from functools import reduce # Only needed in Python3

f = lambda dicts: reduce(lambda acc, el: {**acc, **{k: {**acc.get(k, {}), **v} for k, v in el.items()}}, dicts, {})

f(dicts) # {'A': {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'j': 4, 't': 9}, 'B': {'a': 10, 'c': 31, 'r': 160, 'y': 400}}
```

Note that there is an implicit recursion with the `reduce` function. This provides you with an example of a multi-variable `lambda`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I will try it out and see what I can get